# Как залить файл на FTP под другим названием?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

Есть скрипт для заливки файла на фтп. Все бы хорошо, да только не нашел параметра который отвечает за название файла на удаленном сервере. Есть вариант отдельно подключаться к фтп и переименовывать файл, но думаю это не есть комильфо.

```
ftp -in -u ftp://User:Passwordftp@10.28.1.1/Dir/ Test.files.tgz
```

Comment: А ncftp у вас есть, его как то удобнее для таких вещей использовать. `ncftpput -u User -p Password -C 10.28.1.1 /local/path/file /Dir/remote_file_name`

Comment: его у меня нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

просто укажите нужное вам имя:

```
$ ftp ... ftp://.../каталог/нужное.имя локальный.файл
```

---

кстати, к слову, и программой *curl* можно загружать файлы:

```
$ curl -T локальный.файл ftp://.../каталог/нужное.имя
```